# Parameterization of a piecewise function for differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

I am a little unsure of my answer to a question and I'd like for someone to go over with me because I'm not sure if its complete.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as $$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 
>       x^n & x\leq 1 \\
>      ax+b & x>1
>      \end{cases}$$
> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for which parameters of $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ is $f$ differentiable?

I know that for a function to be differentiable at a point it first has to be continuous at that point and secondly the limit of the derivative must exist at that point so for this case we want 2 things:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=f(1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+}f(x)\implies\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} x^n=1=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+}ax+b\implies a+b=1.$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}f'(x)=f'(1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+}f'(x)\implies \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} nx^{n-1}=n=f'(1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+}a\implies a=n. $$
I don't know if this enough or if there is some other thing that I'm missing out, if there is I'd be glad if you could point it out.

Comment: Looks right to me. You have calculated $a$ and $b$, as requested. Why do you think you need more info?

Comment: @bubba Well it just... feels like there should be more? I don't know what else to really say about it but if what I've done so far seems ok then I guess I'm ok with it.